# Add a DIV around a specific hook in Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to add a DIV around the price and cart hooks in Woocommerce in the Single product page.

The content-single-page.php file looks like this :

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
?>
```

I am looking to add a DIV around these hooks :

```
hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numbers aside are the priorities of the hooked functions, it's just hook your own functions with the right priorities:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hooks_open_div', 7);
function hooks_open_div() {
    echo '<div>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hooks_close_div', 33);
function hooks_close_div() {
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Would you happen to know how to change a hook number in that case?

Comment: You will have to remove it with `remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'HOOK_NAME', PRIORITY_NUMBER)` and add it again. :)

Comment: Thanks. it helped. +1

Comment: This actually worked great.  even on the current version WP 4.9.5 and WooCommerce 3.3.5